# Retrieving html/javascripts webpage after disconnection

Tags: javascript, php, html

Supposed my server is hosting a HTML/JavaScript page "index.html" that contains a bunch of input fields and JavaScript logics. A client comes in, browse the site for a bit, then accidentally got disconnected. Is it possible for the client to visit index.html and retrieve exactly how the user left the page, including texts in input fields and JavaScript states/variables?

Thank you.

Comment: you can store the value in cookies. or you can store the state of user on server side, but I think that would be too much. Depends on how important the data is and how much efficient you want. Quick answer is cookies. Also take care of [cookie limit](http://superuser.com/questions/97625/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-cookie-and-how-many-can-be-stored-in-a-browser-fo)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Web Storage API, it's supported by all modern browsers: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage)